# C - Opening a file inside a function using fopen

Tags: c, fopen

I am using Visual Studio 2005 (C\C++).

I am passing a string into a function as a char array. I want to open the file passed in as a parameter and use it. I know my code works to an extent, because if I hardcode the filename as the first parameter it works perfectly.

I do notice if I look at the value as a watch, the value includes the address aside the string literal. I have tried passing in the filename as a pointer, but it then complains about type conversion with __w64. As I said before it works fine with "filename.txt" in place of fileName. I am stumped.

```
void read(char fileName[50],int destArray[MAX_R][MAX_C],int demSize[2])
{
    int rows=0;
    int cols=0;
    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    FILE * f = fopen(fileName,"r");
...
```

The calling function code is:

```
char in_filename[50];
int dem[MAX_R][MAX_C]; 
int dem_size[2];
get_user_input( in_filename);
read(in_filename, dem, dem_size );
```

In the watch I added for filename the correct text appears, so the data is getting passed in.

Comment: Hm... I do that a lot with MinGW. The function that later opens a file is passed the parametre "const char * filename" - MinGW never ever complained about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `fopen()` then you're coding in C, not C++. Also, this is not how you pass arrays to functions. The syntax for the parameter list is

```
void f(char arr[], unsigned int arr_size);
```

In the case of multidimensional arrays you must specify the size of the right-most dimension explicitly:

```
void f(char arr[][20], unsigned int arr_size);
```

That said, try changing the parameter from `char fileName[50]` to `char* fileName`.

Comment: My mistake - changing the parameter to char * filename succeeds in compile, however the File pointer is invalid, and causes errors when fscan attempts to use it.

Comment: Are you sure the file with that filename exists? Are you sure your working directory is the directory where the file resides?

Comment: I added the calling code in the question.
And yes, I can put "filename.txt" in place on filename and it works fine. This is the same string literal being passed into the function that I see in the watch if i add a watch for filename.

Comment: If the file exists, are you on a Unix (-like) platform? If so, get the output from `getcwd()` (which is in header `unistd.h`) and check it's the directory where the file is. If you're on Windows then the function is `_getcwd()` and I believe it's in header `direct.h`

Comment: I got it figured out. It was my reading in that was the problem. I was including the newline in my read input. After changing this, and taking your advice on the parameter change it worked like a charm.

Thankyou for your advice and help, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Josh: You should test the return value of `fopen()` - if returns `NULL`, then do `perror("fopen");` and you'll get a nice error message telling you what the problem is - which often helps a great deal in tracking down problems like this.