# fopen used in a function includes the file address in a string

Tags: c, fopen, palindrome, ansi-c

I'm working on a Computer Programming assignment to read in lines from a file and determine if it is a(n):

- impure palindrome: Ignores punctuation and case

  for example: *Madam I'm Adam* is an impure palindrome.
- pure palindrome: checks punctuation and case

  e.g. *evil rats on no star live* is a pure palindrome.

I have created functions for both of these cases and they work fine.

My problem lies with opening files

I have a function that reads in a filename from the `argv[]` and it's mean to calculate the number of impure/pure palindromes and the number of lines.  And it also kinda works BUT!!

When I check the output with the `printf` functions I've put in I believe the address of the file is included in when gets is used.  Other than that It works fine. My code also works when I hardcode a filename into it. I think it has something to do with pointers and memory addresses but I'm stumped.

I have read a similar question to this but the answer wasn't provided since the op was able to solve it.

Here is the link: [Opening a file inside a function using fopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755663/c-opening-a-file-inside-a-function-using-fopen)

I didn't think it was necessary to include my pure palindrome and impure palindrome functions for this question. If I'm wrong I am happy to include them.

My read file function:

```
void read_file(const char* filename)
{
bool impure = false;
bool pure = false;

int purecount = 0;
int impurecount = 0;
int linecount = 0;

FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
if (file != NULL)
{
    char line[FILE_LEN];
    char line1[FILE_LEN];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        sscanf(line, "%[^\n]", line1);
        pure = is_a_pure_palindrome(line1);
        impure = is_an_impure_palindrome(line1);
        printf("%s\n", line);

        if (pure == true)
            purecount++;
        else if (impure  == true)
                impurecount++;

        linecount++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    printf("There are %d pure palindromes and %d impure palindromes and %d lines\n", purecount, impurecount, linecount);
}
else
{
    perror("fopen");
}

return;
}
```

My main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i = 0;
        for (;i< argc; i++)
        {
            read_file( argv[i]);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `read_file(argv[0]);` is perhaps not what you want.

Comment: One tip: if you're not sure what's going on, trying printing information like the name of the file you're opening.  When you see your 'read file' function opening your program (instead of the data file), you get an idea of what's going wrong.  Make sure your diagnostic output ends with a newline each time.

Answer (score 3):

`argv[0]` represents program execution path name.
Arguments in C/C++ start from 1.

Change to:

```
int i = 1;
for (;i< argc; i++)
{
    read_file( argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Geez something so simple can muk up the whole program!

Do I indicate this question is solved now or will a moderator change it?